# Как с помощью регулярного выражения проверить начало строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка:
`String string = "Compassion is the basis of morality"`
Как с помощью `string.matches` проверить что строка начинается с "Compassion"?
На сайте https://regex101.com я могу использовать выражение `^Compassion`, однако используя Java я не могу решить задачу используя `string.matches("^Compassion")`.
Как это работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя выражение `^Compassion` матчер вернет `false`, т.к. ожидается, что после слова `Compassion` больше нет символов.

Чтобы пройти проверку на соответствие выражению, используйте `^Compassion(.*)`

Так же, не прибегая к регулярным выражениям, у класса `String` есть метод `startsWith`, который проверит строку на начало:

```
"Compassion is the basis of morality".startsWith("Compassion");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Да, я знаю про startsWith, просто я пытаюсь вникнуть в регулярки (:

Comment: @mArcKrat, пожалуйста)

Comment: Если для решения нужно использовать regex, то символ начала строки не нужен, так как учитывается вся строка, захватывать остальное в группу дополнительно не нужно - `str.matches("Compassion.*");`

Comment: @PotroNik, а ты шаришь :\

Comment: @DmitriyD, это догадки просто, а так вообще не знаю что тут делаю =(